# .ASHX alongside Wordpress

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I am comfortable using the .NET framework to manipulate data in my MSSQL database. Unfortunately, I have a client who is requesting a WordPress site. I would like to use WordPress as requested, but also leverage .NET technology. My idea is to use AJAX to communicate with a standalone (or several different) .ASHX handler files. I have checked with my web host and both ASP.NET and PHP are enabled. My question is will these technologies collide in any manner I need to be aware of? Will I suffer any performance issues? I have little PHP experience and would appreciate input from any who have been down this road.

Comment: What is the .Net part of this site *doing*? Will it need to interact with the WordPress blog?

Comment: I will have a `<script>` on a Wordpress Page that interfaces between the page it is on, and the MSSQL database. (via the .ashx)

Comment: So the wordpress page will have some sort of form elements that will post to an ASHX page? Is it only one page that will be doing this?

Comment: Not a form. An AJAX request that occurs when the page is ready. The data I am looking to retrieve is not just a list of records, and I have the function already in written in .NET. I could absolutely rewrite it in PHP and use that instead of a .ASHX page, but I don't have enough knowledge to do so.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. No, there's no reason why that shouldn't work. If you're planning on using jQuery, one comes bundled with WordPress and you more-or-less are forced to use that version, but other than that, you should have no issues.

Comment: I didn't know about the locked jQuery version, thank you for the heads-up. I will proceed with the project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Javascript to call the ashx handlers and returning string,xml,json from the ashx handlers you will have no problem. You can install Wordpress on Windows, see the Windows Wordpress Installer: http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress, though I guess it won't matter in your case since your hosting provider will handle installation.

Comment: Yes! Return type is JSON. I can handle installation, and I have a MySQL DB ready for WP anyway. The client wants WP as a CMS, but I want the functionality of .NET. This is encouraging to hear, thanks!